# Can't pass a string with JQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I have an input;

```html
 <input id="product" type="button" value="Add To Cart" onclick="addAjax({{=dogProducts[i].name}})"/>
```

The input is fdgdg I verified this buy looking at the page elements. and this Ajax function:

```js
function addAjax(id){
    $("#output").text("") ;
    $("#ajaxerror").text("");
    //alert(id)
    console.log(id);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'/pkpetscart/default/addtocart',
        data: {
            product:id
        },
        timeout: 1000,
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            // place returned value  in the DOM
            jQuery('#output').html(msg)
        },
        error: function(objAJAXRequest, strError){
            $( "#ajaxerror" ).append( " AJAX error:" + strError );
        }
    });
}
```

When I try to run it firebug shows

> ```
> ReferenceError: fdgdg is not defined
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/pkpetscart/default/dogs
> Line 1
> ```

How can I work through this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your parameter in quotes to make it a string, if its not in quotes it is treated as variable which you have not defined. Thus you are getting the error

> ReferenceError: fdgdg is not defined

Use

```
onclick="addAjax('{{=dogProducts[i].name}}')"
```

instead of

```
onclick="addAjax({{=dogProducts[i].name}})"
```

Comment: Sigh...Some times I wonder why I get out of bed :3 Thanks man. I'll give you the thumbs up when the timer runs out.

Comment: @user4021524, It happens with all of us